# Is the subscription in constructor fully ran before the subscriptions on ngoninit begin?

Tags: angular

For example

```
private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();


constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    
}

ngOnInit() {

    // I want this the first subscription to fully finish
    // before the 2nd one gets called
    this.subscription.add(userService.someFunc().subscribe((data) => console.log(data))) // 1st
    this.subscription.add(userService.someFunc().subscribe((data) => console.log(data))) // 2nd
}
```

Since subscribe is async I was wondering how this scenerio works. Is there a chance that ngoninit's subscription finishes first?

If so, is there any way to get constructor's subscription to finish before ngOninit starts?

Comment: I wouldn’t advice running a subscription in the constructor in the first place. If you need to execute in order, use a switchMap or similar operator.

Comment: Okay, I edited my code. Could you show me how to do switchMap on the ngOninit?

Answer (score 0):

```
private destroyed$: ReplaySubject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject(null);
constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    
}

ngOnInit() {
userService.someFunc1().pipe( 
   switchMap((resFromFirst)=>{ return userService.someFunc2()}),
   takeUntil(this.destroyed$)).subsribe((resFromSeconde)=>{})
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next(true);
    this.destroyed$.complete();
}
```

I am using the takeUntil operator with switchMap.

Comment: can this be done without the replaySubject?

Comment: Why not? It should work perfectly ...

Comment: `private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
constructor(private userService: UserService) {    
}
ngOnInit() {
this.subscription = userService.someFunc1().pipe( 
   switchMap((resFromFirst)=>{ return userService.someFunc2()})).subsribe((resFromSeconde)=>{})
}`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer is to do the second subscription inside the first.

I'm sure one of the suggested rxjs functions in the comments does this in a simpler manner, but for all the years I've been doing Angular, I've gotten myself in a rut of 'this works, whatever' and haven't really gone out of my way to learn all the various parts of the billions of components, services, and frameworks that are available to me.

So you'll have to settle for 'basic but functional' I'm afraid.

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
    const fn1Sub = this.service.func1().subscribe((res1: any) => {
        fn1Sub.unsubscribe();
        console.log('Function 1 result: ', res1);

        const fn2Sub = this.service.func2().subscribe((res2: any) => {
            fn2Sub.unsubscribe();
            console.log('Function 2 result: ', res2);
        });

    });
}
```

That's good for one hit when the component loads, assuming that is your desired use case.

Comment: I don't recommend doing subscribe in another subscribe.

Comment: Technically everything after the response comes in is within the subscribe. If you mean simply reading it in that form makes you nauseous, then I agree, it shouldn't be done *directly* inside the subscribe because that's horrible, but in there or calling out to another method so it looks nice, it's *technically* still the same thing.